# Entity Framework: Convert.ToDecimal not supported, any ideas? EF gives an error

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have been doing queries in EF and everything working great but now i have in the db 2 fields that are actually CHAR.. They hold a date but in the form of a number, in SQL Management Studio i can do date1 >= date2 for example and i can also check to see if a number i have falls in between these 2 dates.

Its nothing unusual, but basically a field that represents a date (the number grows as the date does)...

Now in EF when i try to do >= it states you can't do this on a string, ok understand its c# so i tried doing Convert.ToDecimal(date1) but it gives me an error saying that its not supported.

I have no option of changing the db fields, they are set in stone :-(

the way i got it to work was request of details and do a .ToList and then use the .ToDecimal and it works but of course this is doing it in memory! and this defeats the object of EF i.e. for example adding to the query using iqueryable.

Another way i got it to work was to pass the SQL query to SqlQuery of the dbcontext but again i lose a lot of ef functionality.

Can anyone help?

I am really stuck

Comment: What is your context here? Are you trying to do validation? What features of EF are you losing if you call .ToList()?

Comment: I am checking the value of a date in numerical format i.e.  dateStart >= myvar && dateEnd <= myvar ...  this causes an error because dateStart is a string so i did ToDecimal and EF throws an error due to the fact that its not supported. If i call ToList this is effectively executing the query so if i execute this query without my DateRange it may return 1,000,000 records but with my date criteria it may return 5 records. Hence ... To make it work i am doing the Where for the date on the LIST but the query has already been executed..

Comment: Ah, gotcha, thanks for the clarification. @GertArnold has the solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say that you tried `>=` I assume that it would work for you if you could do that in plain SQL. And that is possible by doing

```
String.Compare(date1, date2) >= 0
```

EF is smart enough to translate that into a `>=` operator.

The advantage is that you do not need to compare converted values, so indexes can be used in execution plans.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can at least enable deferred execution of the query by using `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToList()`. This won't change the fact that the database would need to return all the records when you do in fact execute the query, however.

To let the database perform the filtering, you need your query to be compatible with SQL. Since you can't do ToDecimal() in SQL, you need to work with strings directly by converting your `myvar` to a string that is in the same format as `dateStart` and `dateEnd`, then form your query.